# read files and get all the word after a specific word in perl

Tags: regex, perl

This Question may seems a little easy, but I'm a newbie in regex. I am writing a script trying to read following two files "file1" "file2" ,Get the word name after --keep means i want to get the word Machine_Test.2019.01 and do something like reading a file like /tmp/Machine_Test.2019.01 file and check the files status. After that I want to check for the second word after --keep which is Machine_Train.2019.02 and do the same after finish getting all the word in file1 and file2.

example of the files inside file1 & file2 :

```
#!/bin/csh -f

rsh -n machine1 "( run.py --keep Machine_Test.2019.01 --training 300 )

rsh -n machine2 "( run.py --keep Machine_Train.2019.02 --training 300 )
...
```

For the first thought I'm working on some answers and I did a small test on the following:

```
my $file = " /tmp/file1 "
open(FI,$file) or die("Could not open  file.");
foreach my $line (<FI>) {
    if ( my $input =~ /\--keep\s+(\w+)/ ){
        my $found = $1;
        open another file maybe /tmp/$found
        and do something...
    } else {
        printf("no more find\n");
    }
}
close(FI);
```

Can any one tell me whats wrong with my regex on the following, I tried if i set a string my self, and I can get the word after the word --keep with following.

```
$input =~ /\--keep\s+(\w+)/
```

Or is there any way to get the word in the file without reading it line by line, What Can I do to get all the names after ---keep in file1 and file2? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could use `\Q--keep\E\s\K\S+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
 perl -lne ' /--keep\s+(\S+)/ and print "cat /tmp/$1" '
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat owen.txt
#!/bin/csh -f

rsh -n machine1 "( run.py --keep Machine_Test.2019.01 --training 300 )

rsh -n machine2 "( run.py --keep Machine_Train.2019.02 --training 300 )


$ perl -lne ' /--keep\s+(\S+)/ and print "cat /tmp/$1" ' owen.txt
cat /tmp/Machine_Test.2019.01
cat /tmp/Machine_Train.2019.02

$
```

Assuming you have content like

```
$ cat /tmp/Machine_Test.2019.01
ABC

$ cat /tmp/Machine_Train.2019.02
XYZ

$
```

then the command,

```
$ perl -lne ' if ( /--keep\s+(\S+)/ ) { $x=qx(cat /tmp/$1); print "$x" } ' owen.txt
ABC

XYZ


$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
\Q--keep\E\s\K\S+
```

See [**a demo on regexr.com**](https://regexr.com/49cd9).